# VolumeClaim in Kubernetes Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create both a PersistentVolume and a PersistentVolumeClaim on Google Kubernetes Engine.

The way to link them is via labelSelector.
I am creating the objects with this definition:

volume.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-test
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    pv-owner: owner
    pv-usage: pv-test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/test/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-test
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv-usage: pv-test
```

and running:

```
kubectl apply -f volume.yml
```

Both objects are successfully created, however, VolumeClaim apparently keeps pending forever awaiting a Volume that matches its requirements.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `PersistentVolume` resources don’t belong to any namespace. They’re cluster-level resources like nodes, but `PersistentVolumeClaim` objects can only be created in a specific namespace.

Seems like when you created the claim earlier, it was immediately bound to the `PersistentVolume`. Can you show output of the commands:

```
$ kubectl get pv
$ kubectl get pvc
```

Highly likely your `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` was set to `Retain`, so your `PersistentVolume` is in `Released` status now. Since there is no another `PersistenVolume` resource matches your claim's requirements your `PersistentVolumeClaim` is in `Pending` status.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help @konstantin-vustin

I found the solution. I had to specify **storageClassName: manual** attribute in the spec of both objects.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class

According to the doc

> A PV with no storageClassName has no class and can only be bound to PVCs that request no particular class.

So IMO it should have worked before, so I am not sure if I clearly understood it.

This was the status before

```
kubectl get pv pv-test-vol && kubectl get pvc pv-test --namespace openwhisk
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv-test-vol   2Gi        RWO            Retain           Available             manual                   26s
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pv-test   Pending                                       standard       26s
```

The updated definitions

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-test
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    pv-owner: owner
    pv-usage: pv-test
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/test/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-test
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv-usage: pv-test
```

This is the status after

```
kubectl get pv pv-test-vol && kubectl get pvc pv-test --namespace openwhisk
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM               STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv-test-vol   2Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound     openwhisk/pv-test   manual                   4s
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pv-test   Bound     pv-test-vol   2Gi        RWO            manual         4s
```